# Indented print in java

Tags: java, printf, indentation

I have a test code:

```
public class Testinh
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String author = "author";
        String title = "title";
        int pages = 0;
        System.out.print('\u000C');
        System.out.printf("Author : %-10s%nTitle : %-10s%nPages : %-10d", author, title, pages);

    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Author : author    
Title : title     
Pages : 0
```

How do I get it to print everything equally indented, so my output would be :

```
 Author : author    
 Title :  title     
 Pages :  0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the labels the same you do the values; something like

```
System.out.printf("%-8s %-10s%n%-8s %-10s%n%-8s %-10d", "Author :", author, "Title :", title, "Pages :", pages);
```

Or you could just add the needed spaces to your string.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the spaces.**
To help, split the format string on multiple lines.

```
System.out.printf("Author : %s%n" +
                  "Title :  %s%n" +
                  "Pages :  %d",
                  author, title, pages);
```

I removed the left-alignment of the values. Why left-align (pad spaces on right) when there's nothing after the value on that line?